# Swift function not updating drawing

Tags: swift, function, draw, geometry

I have a stepper in my view controller that updates the variables (redd1,greenn1,bluee1). I have a circle that is drawn by over riding the drawRect function. The function updateColor() is suppose to draw a new circle with the updated color from the variables. When I print the new value of the variables they come up correct, but the color of the circle still doesn't change.

```
 func updateColor()
{
    let circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: -25.0, y: 10.0, width: 100.0,    height: 100.0))
    circle.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0;
    let startingColor = UIColor(red: (CGFloat(redd1))/255, green: (CGFloat(greenn1))/255, blue: (CGFloat(bluee1))/255, alpha: 1.0)
    circle.backgroundColor = startingColor;
    addSubview(circle);
    //print(redd1);
}
```

Comment: haven't you tried circle.backgroundColor = newColor?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating and adding a new circle (a `UIView`) each time you want to change the color. Why don't you simply change the color of the existing circle?

```
class Foo: UIView {

    var red: Float = 255
    var green: Float = 0
    var blue: Float = 0

    private let circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: -25.0, y: 10.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0))

    private var circleColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor(
            red: (CGFloat(self.red))/255,
            green: (CGFloat(green))/255,
            blue: (CGFloat(blue))/255,
            alpha: 1.0)
    }

    override init (frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addCircle()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
    }

    private func addCircle() {
        circle.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0
        circle.backgroundColor = self.circleColor
        addSubview(circle)
    }

    func updateColor() {
        circle.backgroundColor = self.circleColor
    }
}
```

[image]